# Python Pandas Pivot based on a Specific row Text

Tags: python, pandas

'''
I have records like this

```
MC                          NewQuestion          Answer_Choice
Question: Question A ?      Question_Text        No_HTML
                            Option               Option A
*                           Option               Option B
Questoin:Question B ?       Question_Text        No_HTML
*                           Option               Option A
                            Option               Option B
                            Option               Option C
```

How I want !

```
MC                      New_Question      Option      Option      Option
Question: Question A ?  Question_Text     Option A    *Option B    
Question: Question B ?  Question_Text    *Option A     Option B   Option C
```

We can rename the Option Column as 1,2,3 but in the actual file its only Option

Transpose Logic is quite complex here any help ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfkPa.jpg)

'''

Comment: Beware to formatting: text that is not formatted as code is simply flowed ignoring new lines and multiple spaces. Here it was hardly if at all understandable. I have done it for you, but you should have a look at my edit to be able to next ask a nicer question :-)

Comment: Yes thats fine thank you :)

Comment: You should add a second record to your sample data, and describe the logic. For example is the number of options always  2? is the text in NewQuestion always `Option`?

Comment: I have made changes kindly have a look thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is not a *transposition* but is *pivoting* in pandas wording.

I would:

- store the `Question_Text`s for future use
- transfer the star (`*`) into the `Answer_Choice` column and clear it in `MC`
- *forward fill* the `MC` column to repeat the question name
- add a number after Option in `NewQuestion` column
- pivot the dataframe
- restore the `Question_Text`s

Code could be:

```
nq = df.loc[df['MC'].str.startswith('Question'), ['MC', 'NewQuestion']
            ].set_index('MC')

df.loc[df['MC'] == r'*', 'Answer_Choice'] = df['MC'] + df['Answer_Choice']

df.loc[~df['MC'].str.startswith('Question'), 'MC'] = np.nan

df = df.ffill().loc[df['NewQuestion'] == 'Option']
df['NewQuestion'] = df['NewQuestion'] + ' '  + (df.groupby('MC').cumcount()+1).astype(str)

df = df.pivot('MC', 'NewQuestion', 'Answer_Choice'
              ).rename_axis(None, axis=1).fillna('') \
              .assign(NewQuestion = nq['NewQuestion']).reset_index()

df = df[['MC', 'NewQuestion'] + df.columns.tolist()[1:-1]]
```

With your sample data, I get:

```
                       MC     NewQuestion   Option 1   Option 2  Option 3
0  Question: Question A ?   Question_Text   Option A  *Option B          
1  Question: Question B ?  QuestionB_Text  *Option A   Option B  Option C
```

Comment: When i concatinate 2 files in a dataframe it gives following error

Comment: ValueError: Location based indexing can only have [labels (MUST BE IN THE INDEX), slices of labels (BOTH endpoints included! Can be slices of integers if the index is integers), listlike of labels, boolean] types